How do I programmatically access Mongo Atlas cluster "logical size", current & max
I'm just trying to keep the database capacity visible in the client app I'm making, because it's not for me, so of course I want the user to see their database consumption, so we can talk about upgrading as it gets closer to filling.
This information is easily visible from the overview page of cloud.mongodb.com:
(https://i.sstatic.net/zsZn625n.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/BHrya1jz.png)
But I'm not sure where to get that information from the mongoDB client driver, if that API can even get said info at all. (I saw that there's a "MongoDB Atlas Administration API (2.0)", but that seems like overkill for what I need..?)
The ListDatabasesResult object from client.db("admin").admin().listDatabases() provides the totalSize and totalSizeMb properties, so that's something, though the values given don't exactly match what I see at cloud.mongodb.com, so I'm not even sure what they are. (totalSize so huge (2,815,279,104), it must be bits? And includes index size? But it still doesn't add up)
So yah if anyone can help me programmatically get the overall cluster sizes to display for the user (e.g. "database consumption: 200 / 512 MB"), I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is a related post: How is the data size of a MongoDB Atlas cluster calculated: document size or storage size?

Have a look at db.stats()

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@prasad_ Yes that is somewhat related, but does not answer my specific question.

@WernfriedDomscheit Those stats pertain to individual databases within the cluster, but not the cluster itself, which imbues the given storage limit based on the tier chosen. If I must loop through each database individually to get precise amounts of memory consumed and add them up, I certainly will, and that's fine. But most of all, I really don't know how to get the cluster maximum programmatically. (If it's possible.)

@Community No... no it's super clear. :/

Yes, db.stats() shows statistics of individual databases but at the end it shows figures of the entire cluster. Have a careful look!
